# Rails I18n Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I am reading [I18N for Active Record Models](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translationsfor-active-recordmodels) but I can't get an attribute on my model to display correctly.

I have a model like this:

```
class Tran < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :description, :presence => true,
                            :length => {:maximum => 100 }
end
```

and a en.yml file like this:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      tran:
        description: "Description"
    errors:
      models:
        tran:
          attributes:
            description:
  errors:
    messages:
      blank: "can't be blank!"
```

When I show the error message on the client, the "can't be blank!" successfully shows up, but the description does not change to "Description" like I would expect.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone?  I just can't get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty relevant to what you want :

[How to change validation messages on forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732664/how-to-change-validation-messages-on-forms)

Comment: I have the same code as him.  When I change the attribute in the top section it correctly changes on my form but not in the error message from ActiveRecord.

Comment: It was actually a problem in my server code and not my .yml file, but for a user searching for help I think your answer will be most relevant so I am going to accept it.